# Are Latin "virīlis", Punjabi "vīr", Old Irish "fer" , Wels "gwr" and Hindi "var" related?

Tags: historical-linguistics, semantics, latin, comparative-linguistics, welsh

Are **all** the words above from the same root (PIE)? Or are these a bunch of false cognates like behtar (Farsi) better (English).

Comment: A related question on [latin.se]: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/5455/are-vir-and-virgo-etymologically-related

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Latin vir, Sanskrit vīra-, Avestan vīra-, Old Irish fer, Lithuanian výras, Gothic wair, all mean “man” and all derive from Indo-European *wīro- (or *uiH-ro).

Comment: Ok, But what about Hindi and Punjabi?

Comment: The Hindi etc. words derive from Sanskrit. http://dsalsrv02.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/philologic/contextualize.pl?p.3.soas.1888789

Comment: But, Hindi has borrowed a lot and so has Punjabi, from Urdu and other languages, also is it necessary that all words derive from Sanskrit?

Comment: Look at the link I gave to Turner’s dictionary. In Hindi bīr is the genuine New Indo-Aryan form; vīr is a loan (tatsama) from Sanskrit.

Comment: Yeah got that now, so we are just left with Punjabi.

Comment: It is all there in Turner. "P. vīrā, bīr m. ʻ brother (address by sister) ʼ, vīr, bīr m. ʻ hero ʼ". "P" means Punjabi.

Comment: oh ok got that now (P)

Comment: Also English _were(wolf)_.

Comment: Also English "world".

Comment: Hindi and Punjabi are Indo-European languages, just like European languages. They have the same roots, being from the same language family. The white people of Europe came from the Indian region, it's the reason why they are called "Indo-European" people. See all the languages of the family here for instance: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4f/IndoEuropeanTree.svg